# scala MutableList when foreach add element why not throw Exception

Tags: list, scala, exception

when I try scala list, I found a question. when I use a MutableList, just want to try append a element in foreach (I know this is a bad operation):

```
import scala.collection.mutable.MutableList
val tts = MutableList("Hello World~")
tts.foreach { t => 
  tts += "Hello World~"
  println(t)
}
```

Console Output:

```
Hello World~
Hello World~
```

My question is why the above code not throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` or output normaly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Throwing the `ConcurrentModificationException` on modifications during iteration is generally called fail-fast semantics. Scala collection classes normally do not throw `ConcurrentModificationException`s because:

- fail-fast complicates the implementation of the iterator
- fail-fast usually slows down the iterator implementation
- fail-fast is hard to guarantee in all cases (even Java classes do not [guarantee it and do it on a best-effort basis](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#fail-fast))
- fail-fast is even harder to ensure in multithreaded code

Because of this reasons, Scala just documents that concurrent modifications are not allowed, rather than striving for fail-fast and ending up with a leaky abstraction.